# How do I get Pandas to recognize a *.zip file?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, zip

**Objective**: I want to read a CSV file contained in a *.zip file

My problem is that Python acts as there is not file.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'N:\\l\\xyz.zip'
```

The code I am using is the below (using a windows machine):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"N:\l\xyz.zip",
                  compression="zip")
```

Any help would be appreciated?

```
data = pd.read_csv("N:\l\xyz.zip",
                  compression="zip")
```

**EDIT**:This is on an s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below code for the zipped file in working directory & it worked

df = pd.read_csv("test_wbcd.zip", compression="zip")

So, the problem should be with the file path. Kindly check your file location.